# VyOS equivalent of "deny unknown-clients" from dhcpd

Tags: isc-dhcp, vyos

I'm attempting to use VyOS as a router and move my dhcp server functionality into it. In my current setup, I have a subnet that only allowed statically mapped clients. I can easily get the static maps to work with VyOS, but I don't know how to correctly implement the "deny unknown-clients" option for the the subnet as I have it set with dhcpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out.

VyOS can take dhcpd.conf options as part of the definition of a subnet with something like the following command:

```
set service dhcp-server shared-network-name ${networkname} subnet ${subnetip/cidr} subnet-parameters "${exact dhcpd.conf string}"
```

In my particular case, this became:

```
set service dhcp-server shared-network-name private-subnet subnet 192.168.4.0/24 subnet-parameters "deny unknown-clients"
```